# Increasing game's system compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, xna

I wrote this game on my windows 8, in visual studio 2013, C#. I am now trying to get it to run on an older system that can only run up to .net framework 3.5. I wrote it using a monogame template, and i don't mind if i have to change the code.

so far i've tried lowering the target .net framework to 3.5. The compiler didn't like that, and wouldn't let me use the xna framework 4.0.0.0, so I found an old dll of xna framework 1.0.0.0 and used that. the compiler accepted it, but so many of the classes that I was using before don't exist in that version.

I have been unable to find any version of the xna framework that runs with .net framework 3.5, or think of any solution that doesn't involve changing the xna framework. If someone could point me in the right direction, or give me access to the newest version of the xna framework that works with .net framework 3.5, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install .NET framework on that system? In most cases you need to make your game ship with .NET 4.0 or above to use xna on that old system. Since MonoGame is cross-platform you can also spread it across Linux and Mac OSX.

A side note: XNA has been discontinued in favour of DirectX. I used it before, but now I see at as a lost clause.

Either go Mono framework all the way or choose from other frameworks, such as ANX, OpenTK. Although i'm not a huge fan of it, I can also suggest trying Unity.

Comment: that system is unable to run anything higher than 3.5, so i have to resort back to a low version of xna.

Comment: Seeing as even Windows XP is able to run .NET Framework 4.0, what could this system possibly be running that would be able to play your game?